# TinyMCE & Dynamics

Tags: tinymce, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

We have integrated tinymce with our dynamics instance. This was not set up by our current team but a previous outsourced development team.

The issue is that the tinymce editor loads okay for one entity but not another. They both use the same web resource which contains the tinymce.init function

I'm not sure why we are receiving an error in one entity but not another for the tinymce editor

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#xrmtinymce',
browser_spellcheck: true,
    height: 600,
    max_height: 600,
    plugins: [
'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
      'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
      'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code',
'powerpaste media'
 ],
    toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | code',
    init_instance_callback : function(ed) {
debugger;
            ed.on('keyup',function(e) {
                    var content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();

                    var field = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute(_fieldName);
                    var maxLength = field.getMaxLength();

                    
                    if (content.length > maxLength) {
                      parent.Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Maximum length exceeded. Should be below: " + maxLength);
                    }

                    
                    field.setValue(content);
            });
          }
  });
```

We would greatly appreciate any guidance or assistance in resolving this error!
[A Dynamics Error Has Occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsWZR.png)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q51HJ.png)

Please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide

Answer (score 0):

From your code I can't be sure how TinyMCE has been inserted and if done in a supported way (maybe a Web Resource?).

However because your instance is Online, you can look at PCF controls, one implementing TinyMCE is the following: https://pcf.gallery/tinymce-rich-text-editor/

Details here: https://andz88.wordpress.com/2019/10/23/new-pcf-tinymce-rich-text-editor/

Source code and managed solution managed: https://github.com/andz88/PCF.TinyMCE